# Yii2 Krajee Datepicker plugin - update startDate

Tags: php, yii2, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using the [Krajee Datepicker](https://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datepicker) and I have two Date Input fields (from and to).
I want to set the startDate of the "to" input field to the selected value from "from" input field.
So I made something like this:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'from')->widget(DatePicker::class, [
        'type'          => DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_APPEND,
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'autoclose'      => TRUE,
            'format'         => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'startDate'      => new \yii\web\JsExpression('new Date()'),
            'todayHighlight' => TRUE,
        ],
        'pluginEvents' => [
            'changeDate' => 'function(e){
                 $( "#model-to" ).kvDatepicker("option", "startDate", e.date);
            }'
        ]
    ]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'to')->widget(DatePicker::class, [
        'type'          => DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_APPEND,
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'autoclose'      => TRUE,
            'format'         => 'dd.mm.yyyy',
            'startDate'      => new \yii\web\JsExpression('new Date()'),
            'todayHighlight' => TRUE,
        ],
    ]) ?>
```

The Default value I set in the pluginOptions work quite fine. 
But as soon as I change the "from" date, the "to" Datepicker ignores the startDate completely (even the old startDate). Even the language settings are gone...

I also tried to use `datepicker` instead of `kvDatepicker`. But this throws the error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Answer (score 0):

ok finally I have a solution
The widget creates a new element and appends `-kvdate` to the id.

So if I use this element I can start a call like this and it works quite fine:

> $("#model-to-kvdate").data("datepicker").setStartDate(e.date);